# PHP Count then add content after 16th

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a menu with 21 main items and most of them have their own sub-items.
I want to be able to show only the first '16' of them - `$menu_number['VALUE']` contains this value in the database, so only the first 16 will be shown normally, the rest of them should be available under a "More" item placed after the 16th main item, which will contain the rest of the items and their sub-items.

This is now:

Home

Services > Service 1, Service 2

Portfolio > Portfolio 1, Portfolio 2

.....

Projects > Project 1, Project 2, Project 3

About Us > Sub-Item 1, Sub-Item 2

Contact > Sub-Item 1, Sub-Item 2

This is how it should look like:

Home

Services > Service 1, Service 2

Portfolio > Portfolio 1, Portfolio 2

.....

Projects > Project 1, Project 2, Project 3

More > About Us ( > sub-item1, sub-item2), Contact ( > sub-item1, sub-item2)

This is the current code:

```
$menu_number = mysql_fetch_array($menu_number, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $menu_number['VALUE'];

$counter = 0;
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: Query Failed! " .mysql_error());
    $output = "<nav><ul>";
    while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rs['Link'] = preg_replace('/\|.*$/','',$rs['Link']);
        $output .= "<li class='menu_top' id='".$rs['ID']."'><a href='".$rs['Link']."'>".$rs['Name']."</a>".++$counter;
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '".$rs['ID']."' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: Query Failed! " .mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result2) != 0) {
          $output .= "<ul class='menu_sublinks' id='".$rs['ID']."'>";
          while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
          $rs2['Link'] = preg_replace('/\|.*$/','',$rs2['Link']);
             $output .= "<li class='menu_sublink' id='".$rs['ID']."'><a href='".$rs2['Link']."'>".$rs2['Name']."</a></li>";
          }
          $output .= "</ul></li>";
       }
    }
    $output .="</ul></nav";
```

I have a counter already `$counter` , now I need to find a way to add a `<li>More</li>` and a new `<ul>` inside, containing the 17...21 `<li>`..

I hope I explained good enough, I tried myself to do this but I am confused a little..
Thank you for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats easy enough, just add another while loop near the end of the first one..

```
if ( $counter >= 17 ) {
    $output .= '<ul>';
    while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        /* Add li's of id's > 17 here... */
    }
    $output .= '<ul>';
}
$output .= "</ul></li>";
```

The inner while will simply keep pulling results from the end.

Additionally. Try moving to `mysqli_*` functions as soon as possible as `mysql_*` are deprecated and will in due time be removed from php.

ps. You are missing the closing bracket of `</nav` at the end of your code..

another ps. Consider switching to _fetch_object instead of array and then using `$rs->Link`, `$rs->ID` etc. IMHO thats much more readable then the bracket mess that arrays cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if (counter == 16)
  {
     echo "<li>more...</li></ul><ul>";

     // Other existing code in the while loop goes here.
  }
}
```

This will add the code in the iteration of the 17th item, which is better, because you wouldn't want to add 'more', if there isn't more.

But although it's fairly easy to add this code in PHP, I'd rather do it in Javascript, because Javascript will also have to handle the toggling of the visible item. Therefor, if there's no Javascript, it's better to have just a long list of items than a short list, a `more`-list and then nothing...